How to place images below the title?
The below code produces 3 images next to each other, with each image having a caption, and ending with a general caption below all 3 images.
My document has a title with an author block, then an abstract and some sections with paragraphs of text. When I compile this code my text from the Introduction fills the first page, and my images are sent to the top of the next page. Also,the document uses 2 columns (hence the asterix after figure).
How can I position the images above the abstract, below the title?
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

 \usepackage[super]{nth}
 
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    
\begin{document}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\title{foo}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{foo}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{foo} \\
foo, foo \\
foo}
}

\maketitle
\begin{figure*}[!th]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{11\% of full render time}
        \label{fig:sceneProgressA}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{52\% of full render time}
        \label{fig:sceneProgressB}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Full render time}
        \label{fig:sceneProgressC}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Pictures of streaming progress}
    \label{fig:rendering_progress}
\end{figure*}

\begin{abstract}
Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Foo bar baz.


\end{document}

What have I tried?

float package using [H] after figure*
Changing the position of \maketitle
Use minipages instead

What it looks like:

What it should look like:

I omitted most text because of privacy concerns.
Please keep in mind that I am new to LaTeX.
Thank you in advance.
EDIT: If you change IEEEtran to article the images seem to get positioned correctly (almost), but I don't think I can change this.

LaTeX places column spanning floats like figure* and table* are always on the top of the next page or as float pages. Option [!h] or [H] makes not sense here. Packages dblfloatfix and stfloats additionally support bottom placed column spanning floats. But I do not know, if these are compatible with your class, and unfortunately your code is not a minimal working example so I cannot test it. However, this would not lead to the wanted result, but to an alternative one.

@cabohah I changed the code to a MWE

I'm not sufficiently familiar with IEEEtran, but at least some document classes explicitly forbid two-column floats on the first page.  There is a hack to place such a float at the bottom of the first page: How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?  There is also the package stfloats.

@barbarabeeton As already told in my first comment stfloats would help to place the figure at the bottom of the page, but not at top below the document title, IMHO.

For mysterious reasons, those templates have a definition of \BibTeX. You can safely remove it: it has no purpose whatsoever.

You might hook into \@maketitle, that's the macro responsible for printing the title.
However, there are a few things you should be aware of:

hyperref should go last
caption and subcaption are not compatible with IEEEtran and using them causes all captions to be typeset in a style that's not wanted by IEEE, which may trigger rejection of your submission. You can see in the image below that IEEE's style is to have captions flush left, never centered like they're printed if you load caption (maybe through subcaption). With

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

the problem goes away. However, the syntax for subfloats is different, see the code.
I put comments next to a few disabled packages, too.
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{textcomp}% useless
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
%\usepackage{subcaption} % not compatible with IEEEtran
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}% should go last

% this is just for this example
\usepackage{lipsum}

% hook into \@maketitle to add the wanted figure
\AddToHook{cmd/@maketitle/after}{\ADDINITIALFIGURE}
% the code for the figure
\newcommand{\ADDINITIALFIGURE}{%
  % we want to emulate a fixed float
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}
    % pretend we're inside figure
    \expandafter\def\csname @captype\endcsname{figure}%
    % insert the subfloats
    \subfloat[11\% of full render time\label{fig:sceneProgressA}]{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\hfill
    \subfloat[52\% of full render time\label{fig:sceneProgressB}]{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\hfill
    \subfloat[Full render time\label{fig:sceneProgressC}]{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }
    % the text is processed a few times, so we reset the counter each time
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \captionof{figure}{Pictures of streaming progress\label{fig:rendering_progress}}
  \end{minipage}}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
 
\begin{document}

\title{foo}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{foo}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{foo} \\
foo, foo \\
foo}
}

\maketitle



\begin{abstract}
Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{figure}[ht]

\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Test caption}

\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}


Not relevant, but for mysterious reasons the template provided by IEEE contains the silly part
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

which is wrong under many respects and, above all, is completely useless. Remove it. Also the instruction \graphicspath is better placed in the preamble, as it is a global setting.

This answer gives me great results too, I even prefer this version so I am marking it as the solution. Keep in mind that @cabohah's solution works aswell. Thank you so much for the effort put in your answer!

LaTeX provides column spanning floats only with options t and/or p, but not h. Also option H of package float cannot be used with figure* or table* (or the star version of other new defined floats).
You could use the \twocolumn trick and avoid using a float:
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

 \usepackage[super]{nth}
 
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\title{foo}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{foo}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{foo} \\
foo, foo \\
foo}
}

\twocolumn[{%
  \csname @twocolumnfalse\endcsname
  \maketitle
  \captionsetup{type=figure}% Tell (sub)caption, that this is a figure
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{11\% of full render time}
        \label{fig:sceneProgressA}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{52\% of full render time}
        \label{fig:sceneProgressB}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Full render time}
        \label{fig:sceneProgressC}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Pictures of streaming progress}
    \label{fig:rendering_progress}
}]

\begin{abstract}
Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Foo bar baz.

\end{document}


As an alternative you can misuse \author, but in this case you also have to manually correct the figure number:
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

 \usepackage[super]{nth}
 
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\title{foo}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{foo}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{foo} \\
foo, foo \\
foo}
\vskip 2\baselineskip
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}% Otherwise, you will get Fig. 3 instead of Fig. 1!!!
  \captionsetup{type=figure}% Tell (sub)caption, that this is a figure
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{11\% of full render time}
        \label{fig:sceneProgressA}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{52\% of full render time}
        \label{fig:sceneProgressB}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Full render time}
        \label{fig:sceneProgressC}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Pictures of streaming progress}
    \label{fig:rendering_progress}
\end{minipage}
}

  \maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Foo bar baz.


\end{document}

Last but not least, you can use package stfloats to place the figure at the bottom of the first page:
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{blindtext}

 \usepackage[super]{nth}
 
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\usepackage{stfloats}

\begin{document}

%\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\title{foo}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{foo}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{foo} \\
foo, foo \\
foo}
}

\maketitle
\begin{figure*}[b]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{11\% of full render time}
        \label{fig:sceneProgressA}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{52\% of full render time}
        \label{fig:sceneProgressB}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Full render time}
        \label{fig:sceneProgressC}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Pictures of streaming progress}
    \label{fig:rendering_progress}
\end{figure*}

\begin{abstract}
Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.Foo bar baz.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\Blindtext[5]


\end{document}


The package dblfloatfix that I've also suggested in my first comment to your question, seem to not work with IEEEtran. If you replace \usepackage{stfloats} with \usepackage{dblfloatfix}, the figure is still printed at top of the second page.
AFAIK there isn't any package, that supports column spanning floats with option h (or H). So IMHO you need to either use one of the tricks aka hacks or a bottom placed figure with stfloats or a top placed figure at the top of the next page.

This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.
